# TextView в Android Studio

Tags: android

Создал `ScrollView` и разместил на нем `TextView` с `android:id="@+id/textview1"`.

После этого записал вот этот java код:

```
public class Textfile extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.textlist);
        TextView text (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        text.setText("Какой-то текст");}
```

Код выдает ошибку в последней и предпоследней строке, а именно:

```
TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
text.
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
```

Comment: А каким образом можно изменять цвет или размер шрифта в любых строках?

Comment: setTextSize() размер шрифта
setTypeFace() шрифт

Answer (score 0):

Перед `onCreate` определите текствью:

```
TextView textview1;
```